# mongoimport on csv: bare " in non-quoted-field

Tags: mongodb, csv

Running mongoimport, I get the error:

`Failed: read error on entry #2: line 3, column 25: bare " in non-quoted-field`

This is line 3:

`1,0xcrypton,"Hyderabad, India","'Hyderabad', ' India'",17.38405,78.45636`

There are plenty of other questions about this error, but they're all related to double quotes or escaped quotes. There's none of that here. In fact, to be on the safe side I deleted all double quotes from the csv. What's going on?

edit: Also tried removing the entire rest of the csv so it's just this line and the header line. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this happened because I created the csv using pandas `to_csv` and used the `encoding='utf16'` option. Apparently doing so breaks quotation marks.